# Aspen IP21 Tag Value querying with R

Tags: r, excel, odbc, add-in, aspen

I wish to query(read) IP21 tag values using my R script. Is there a way to do that? The closest I have come is populating an excel sheet with the ASPEN add-in functionality and then reading the values in R. Is there a direct way to read the values from IP21? Does IP21 ODBC help?

Comment: From a quick review you should be able to use the RODBC package since IP21 does support ODBC. The key will be figuring out the connection string and reading the RODBC vignette.

Answer (score 1):

```
DRIVER={AspenTech SQLplus};HOST=yelm
```

Taken from the documentation. Works with RODBC.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the documentation?